# Dynamically constructing a query with the `arrow` package in R

Tags: r, dplyr, parquet, apache-arrow

I'm using the `arrow` package to interface with a large (30GB) dataset of parquet files in R. This works great when I have a single clear query but when I try to construct queries dynamically I'm unsure of best practice because the best solution I have requires the use of `eval(parse(text=))`, so I'm looking for better solutions.

As an example, I have the simple dataset below:

```
library(arrow)
artab <- arrow_table(int=1:1000, value=runif(1000))
```

I'd like to retrieve all the rows with values between 0.4 and 0.6, which is trivial to implement with the `dplyr` syntax:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table) # for %between% operator syntax
artab %>%
  filter(value%between%c(0.4, 0.6)) %>%
  collect()
```

This also still works well when I have multiple "windows" I'd like to extract the data within using the `|` OR operator:

```
artab %>%
  filter(value%between%c(0.4, 0.6) | value%between%c(0.8, 1.0)) %>%
  collect()
```

However, if I have a long list of windows and want to generate this query programmatically, the only option I've been able to come up with is constructing the entire pipe chain as a character vector then passing it to `eval(parse(text=))`:

```r
window_req_string <- data.frame(
  lower_bound=c(0.1, 0.4, 0.8), 
  upper_bound=c(0.2, 0.6, 1.0)
  ) %>%
  summarise(req_cmd=paste0("value%between%c(", lower_bound, ", ", upper_bound, 
                           ")", collapse="|")) %>%
  pull(req_cmd)
full_arrow_req <- paste0(
  'artab %>% filter(', window_req_string, ') %>% dplyr::collect()'
)
arrow_output <- eval(parse(text=full_arrow_req))
```

Is there a better way of doing this? It doesn't seem like the [user-defined functions](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/register_scalar_function.html) are a good option here because the function already exists (`filter`), I just need a vectorized version. I'd especially like a better way of doing this because the pipe chains I pass can also grow quite long (filtering on additional columns and running calculations).

I wondered if fiddling with the `R6` object itself to forcibly insert the query (e.g. write the query minus this particular filtering step, then edit the R6 object to "add" this to the list of steps) was a good idea but I'm not super familiar with R6 and that seems very hacky.

**Is there a way to dynamically construct an `arrow` query in R besides writing it as a character string and using `eval(paste())`?**

ETA: here's some timing details I got when running the `lapply` option suggested by @Niklas in the comments on the real dataset. The `lapply` method is slower than the `eval` method by a factor of however many windows I have, so here it was run with 10 windows and gets worse as I add more.

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(eval_method(), lapply_method(), times = 3)
Unit: seconds                                      
            expr       min       lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
   eval_method()  2.265549  2.39105  2.442369  2.516551  2.53078  2.545009     3
 lapply_method() 22.220470 22.70415 22.881048 23.187827 23.21134 23.234848     3
```

Comment: You could create a list of vectors `req_list <- list(c(0.1, 0.2), c(0.4, 0.6), c(0.8, 1.0))` and use `lapply(req_list, \(window) {artab %>%
  filter(value%between%window) %>%
  collect()}) %>% bind_rows()`. That should do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Once [apache/arrow#29841](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/29841) is resolved, you can also do an inequality join using dplyr's `join_by` and `>=`/`<=` (I don't know if it'll support `between` in the nonequi joins, tbd). I think Niklas's suggestion for an iterative approach is likely the best you can do with dplyr/arrow until then. As an alternative, you might (unverified!) be able to do something using `duckdb` and its parquet-interfacing.

Comment: @Niklas Unfortunately that method turns out to be a lot slower than passing the entire sequence at once. The `arrow` internals are a heck of a lot faster at parsing through the file than R is at opening and closing the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddling with the R6 object doesn't feel like the right path, as internally these queries are based around taking and evaluating expressions via tidy eval.  I'd probably do something like this:

```r
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

tbl <- tibble::tibble(x = 1:10)
ranges <- list(c(1, 3), c(5,6), c(9, 10))

calls <- map(ranges, ~call2("between", as.name("x"), .x[[1]], .x[[2]]) )
filter_string <- paste(calls, collapse = "|")

# works in dplyr
tbl |>
  filter(!! rlang::parse_expr(filter_string))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 1
#>       x
#>   <int>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
#> 3     3
#> 4     5
#> 5     6
#> 6     9
#> 7    10
  
# works in arrow too!
output <- arrow_table(tbl) |>
  filter(!! rlang::parse_expr(filter_string))

output
#> Table (query)
#> x: int32
#> 
#> * Filter: ((((x >= 1) and (x <= 3)) or ((x >= 5) and (x <= 6))) or ((x >= 9) and (x <= 10)))
#> See $.data for the source Arrow object

collect(output)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 1
#>       x
#>   <int>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
#> 3     3
#> 4     5
#> 5     6
#> 6     9
#> 7    10
```

Admittedly we're still in the realms of constructing and evaluating strings, but it's perhaps a tiny bit cleaner?

Comment: Yeah, I guess avoiding the string evaluation is the part that felt gross to me to begin with but maybe there really just isn't a better way of handling it. Is there a reason to prefer `rlang` over `base` parse/eval things? Seems like `!!parse_expr` is just `eval(parse(` for these purposes.

Comment: The key difference for me is that I've restricted the string parsing to the expression passed into the filter rather than the entire pipeline, so there's less room for error when extending the pipeline.  

For what it's worth, when I implemented bindings in arrow for `dplyr::across()`, I used `rlang::parse_expr` at some point in the internal logic, as it ended up being the only reasonable solution I could find at the time.

Comment: Thanks Nic, it's nice to have a definitive answer from the maintainer and I agree that parsing only the `filter` expression is safer and simpler.